# ReasonML Type mismatch with same type

Tags: types, ocaml, functor, reason, bucklescript

I'm receiving a type mismatch even though I'm using the same type in ReasonML.  The error is:

```
[1]   We've found a bug for you!
[1]   /Users/gt/work/real-and-open/frontend/src/domain/classroom/views/RosterLayoutHeader.re 42:10-70
[1]
[1]   40 ┆ <Classroom.Mutation.AddStudent>
[1]   41 ┆   ...{
[1]   42 ┆     (addStudent: (~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, unit) => unit) =>
[1]         {
[1]   43 ┆       <div>
[1]   44 ┆         <StudentRowHeader
[1]
[1]   This pattern matches values of type
[1]     (~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, unit) => unit
[1]   but a pattern was expected which matches values of type
[1]     AddStudent.ContainerMutation.mutationFunctionType (defined as
[1]       AddStudent.MutationInternals.mutationFunctionType)
```

When I replace `addStudent: (~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, unit) => unit` with `addStudent: AddStudent.MutationInternals.mutationFunctionType`

The error becomes:

```
[1]   We've found a bug for you!
[1]   /Users/gt/work/real-and-open/frontend/src/domain/classroom/views/RosterLayoutHeader.re 53:61-70
[1]
[1]   51 ┆ _ =>
[1]   52 ┆   updateClassroom(
[1]   53 ┆     Classroom.Action.ApolloAddStudent(() => addStudent(
[1]   54 ┆       ~id=classroom.local.newStudentId |> Student.Model.getUUIDFromId,
[1]   55 ┆       ~classroomId=classroom.data.id,
[1]
[1]   This expression has type AddStudent.MutationInternals.mutationFunctionType
[1]   It is not a function.
```

In the code AddStudent looks like the following:

```
[@bs.config {jsx: 3}];
module Mutation = [%graphql
  {|
    mutation addStudent($id: ID!, $classroomId: ID!) {
      addStudent(student: {id: $id, classroomId: $classroomId}){
        ...Classroom_Model.Fragment.ClassroomFields
      }
    }
  |}
];

module MutationInternals : ApolloMutation.MutationInternal = {
  type mutationFunctionType = (~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, unit) => unit;
  let componentName = "AddStudent";

  module Config = Mutation;
  module InternalMutation = ReasonApollo.CreateMutation(Config);

  let callMutationWithApollo = (apolloMutation : ApolloMutation.apolloMutationType(Config.t)) => 
    ((~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, ()): unit => {
      let newStudent = Config.make(~id, ~classroomId, ());
      apolloMutation(
        ~variables=newStudent##variables,
        // ~refetchQueries=[|"member"|],
        // ~optimisticResponse=Config.t,
        (),
      ) |> ignore;
      () |> ignore;
    }: mutationFunctionType);
};

module ContainerMutation = ApolloMutation.CreateMutationContainer(MutationInternals);

module Jsx2 = ContainerMutation.Jsx2;
let make = ContainerMutation.make;
```

So notice 3 things

1) The type: `type mutationFunctionType = (~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, unit) => unit;` is referenced here and in the error it says `AddStudent.MutationInternals.mutationFunctionType` is mismatched with `(~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, unit) => unit` even though they are the same.

2) When I reference the type directly in the calling function it says `mutationFunctionType` is not a function and it is a function.

3) That I am using a Functor to process my MutationInternals modules... I wonder if that affects the types.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AddStudent.MutationInternals.mutationFunctionType` type is abstract and the compiler doesn't know that underneath the hood it actually is implemented as a function of type

```
(~id: UUID.t, ~classroomId: UUID.t, unit) => unit
```

It is hard to guess, what is the root of the problem in your case. Either you accidentally over abstracted your code, by sealing your module, or you are trying to break the necessary abstraction. In any case, compiler is stopping your from doing it.

Usually, this kind of errors happen when you seal your module, e.g., when you add a module type, e.g.,

```
module type S = {type t};
module M : S = { type t = int};
```

This makes the type `M.t` abstract, so it won't be usable in the context where `int` is expected. The solution is to either remove this unnecessary sealing, e.g.,

```
module type S = {type t};
module M = { type t = int};
```

or tell the compiler explicitly, that `t` is not an abstract type, but a concrete `int`, e.g.,

```
module type S = {type t};
module M: S with type t = int = {
  type t = int;
};
```

Note, in your case I'm talking about this piece of code

```
MutationInternals : ApolloMutation.MutationInternal
```

which hides the `mutationFunctionType` definition.

Comment: `ApolloMutation.MutationInternal` was coercing it.  Removing it and a few more bugs fixed my issue.  Thanks a lot!